# How to split binary data and convert it into numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, struct, binary, unpack

I'm reading keyboard events from `/dev/input/`. Those are [input_event structs](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.3/include/uapi/linux/input.h#L28), respectively five numbers as 24 bytes in little endian format.

This is my current solution:

```
$hex = bin2hex(fread($dev, 24));
$time = floatval(unpack("Q", (pack('H*', substr($hex, 0, 16))))[1].".".unpack("Q", (pack('H*', substr($hex, 16, 16))))[1]);
$type = intval(unpack("S", (pack('H*', substr($hex, 32, 4))))[1]);
$code = intval(unpack("S", (pack('H*', substr($hex, 36, 4))))[1]);
$value = intval(unpack("l", (pack('H*', substr($hex, 40, 8))))[1]);
```

There **must** be a more efficient way to do this in PHP. Anyone? Bueller?

UPDATE:

An example blob would be:

```
$raw = hex2bin("f478cd5d0000000026680d000000000001002e0001000000");
```

This results in:

```
$time = 1573746932.8786;
$type = 1;
$code = 46;
$value = 1;
```

The actual structure looks like this:

```
struct input_event {
    timeval time;
    __u16 type;
    __u16 code;
    __s32 value;
};
```

where timeval is:

```
struct timeval {
    __u64 sec;
    __u64 usec;
}
```

Comment: Just to help testing - can you generate some test data (not sure how) which provides data for the `fread($dev, 24)` and the output expected.

Comment: Also some more detail on the data you're working with might be helpful. There are so many conditional compilation blocks in that struct definition, it's hard to tell what the end result might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could unpack it as a single value.

```
<?php
$raw = fread($dev, 24);
$data = unpack("Ptime1/Ptime2/vtype/vcode/Vvalue", $raw);
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [time1] => 1573746932
    [time2] => 878630
    [type] => 1
    [code] => 46
    [value] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, there are no real floating point values:

```
 (gdb) ptype struct input_event
 type = struct input_event {
     struct timeval time;
     __u16 type;
     __u16 code;
     __s32 value;
 }

 (gdb) ptype struct timeval
 type = struct timeval {
     __time_t tv_sec;
     __suseconds_t tv_usec;
 }

 (gdb) ptype __time_t
 type = long

 (gdb) ptype __suseconds_t
 type = long

 (gdb) ptype __u16
 type = unsigned short

 (gdb) ptype __u16
 type = unsigned short

 (gdb) ptype __s32
 type = int
```

Since that's the case you simply could do some binary work:

```
<?
// Converts your data to byte array
$d = unpack('C*', fread($dev, 24));

// Calculate whatever you desire ...
$tv_sec = ($d[1]<<56) + ($d[2]<<48) + ($d[3]<<40) + ($d[4]<<32) + ($d[5]<<24) + ($d[6]<<16) + ($d[7]<<8) + ($d[8]<<0);
?>
```

That's just a basic example - I was too lazy to check for endianness.